# Which port forwarding is better?

Tags: port-forwarding

There are two methods enabling port forwarding, by entering

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.eth1.route_localnet=1
```

or uncomment the next line

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, the first command specific the name of Ethernet.

Which one is better for privacy?

Answer (score 0):

`net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` is better. The first approach would be unnecessary and generally wrong for simple port forwarding. I will quote the official kernel documentation regarding `route_localnet`

> route_localnet - BOOLEAN  Do not consider loopback addresses as
> martian source or destination     while routing. This enables the use of
> 127/8 for local routing purposes.     default FALSE

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

Comment: `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` doesn't specific which ethernet name, is it enable all?

Answer (score 0):

These are two different options.
There may be several local addresses on your machine, including a loop back. For example, to forward port 8080 from 127.0.0.1 to the external interface ens0 with the address 192.168.0.1:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.ens0.route_localnet=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens0 -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1
```

The service on the socket 127.0.0.1:8080 will be available from 192.168.0.1:8080.
This can be clearly seen in the following abstraction:
Switch "localhost source [YN]" which comes after "mangle PREROUTING"
[image: iptables processing flowchart]